# $zip Rename Functions Not Working in PHP

Tags: php, zip, extract, rename

I am extracting a zip file in PHP and trying to rename it to content.txt. Here is my code:

```
    if($this->copyFile($this->src,$this->dest)) {
        $this->log .= "Successfully copied the file. Starting unzip.<br />";
        $res = $this->zip->open($this->dest);
        if ($res === TRUE) {
            $this->zip->extractTo("/htdocs/content-refresh/");
            $this->extracted = $this->zip->getNameIndex(0);
            $this->log .= "Extracted ".$this->extracted." onto our server.<br />";
            if($this->zip->renameIndex(0,'content.txt')) {
                $this->log .= "Renamed update file to content.txt.<br />";
            } else {
                $this->log .= "Could not rename update file to content.txt.<br />";
            }
            $this->zip->close();
            $this->log .= "The update file is ready to go. Now you can use the update functions.<br />";
        } else {
            $this->log .= "Could not unzip the file.<br />";
        }
    }
```

Here is the file output:

```
Successfully copied the file. Starting unzip.

Extracted Hotel_All_Active 01-19-11.txt onto our server.

Renamed update file to content.txt.

The update file is ready to go. Now you can use the update functions.
```

The problem is that it does not rename the file. I have also tried:

```
$this->zip->renameName(strval($this->extracted),'content.txt')
```

But that also prints out that it renamed the file, but does not. Am I doing something wrong here, or is this function buggy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`renameIndex()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-renameindex.php) function is for renaming a file *inside* an archive.

Looking at the code in the PHP Manual for that function, it's you can see it's modifying the archive:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->renameIndex(2,'newname.txt');
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo 'failed, code:' . $res;
}
```

You need to use the [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function instead.

Comment: Thank you! You are correct. The PHP.net documentation doesn't explain that very well.